# A CSS flexbox issue, need to arrange multiple containers with same width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a footer menu with multiple blocks.

A `block-menu-block` with a menu with 1 to 3 unordered list items (`.menu-block-2 .menu li`).

And multiple `.block-block` items.

What i want, is the footer to assign the same width to the `.block-menu-block ul.menu li` and `block-block` items. So if the footer is like the example, then 25% width to every items. And if the menu is like the code block, but three `.block-block` items, then assign 20% to every items.

```
-[region-footer]-----------------------------------------
|             |             |             |             |
|ul.menu.li 1 | ul.menu.li 2|block-block-2|block-block-1|
|             |             |             |             |
|             |             |             |             |
---------------------------------------------------------

\------ block-menu-block---/
```

every of the four blocks should be 25%

```
-[region-footer]-------------------------------------------------------
|             |             |             |             |             |
|ul.menu.li 1 | ul.menu.li 2|block-block-3|block-block-2|block-block-1|
|             |             |             |             |             |
|             |             |             |             |             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Every of the blocks should be 20%

```
<div class="region region-footer">
  <div id="block-menu-block-2" class="block block-menu-block">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="menu-block-wrapper menu-block-2 menu-name-menu-footer parent-mlid-0 menu-level-1">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="first expanded menu-mlid-734"><span class="nolink">Headline</span>
            <ul class="menu">
              <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-735"><a href="http://google.com">One page</a></li>
              <li class="last leaf menu-mlid-736"><a href="http://google.com">Another page</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="last expanded menu-mlid-785 social-menu-block"><span class="nolink">Social links</span>
            <ul class="menu">
              <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-784"><a href="http://facebook.com" class="social-facebook">Facebook</a></li>
              <li class="leaf menu-mlid-787"><a href="http://linkedin.com" class="social-linkedin">Linkedin</a></li>
              <li class="leaf menu-mlid-786"><a href="http://twitter.com" class="social-twitter">Twitter</a></li>
              <li class="last leaf menu-mlid-788"><a href="http://youtube.com" class="social-youtube">Youtube</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="block-block-2" class="block block-block">
    <h2>Some content</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, minim molestie argumentum est at, pri legere torquatos instructior ex. Vis id odio atomorum oporter.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="block-block-1" class="block block-block">
    <h2>Website info</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Address 9</p>
      <p>Zip city</p>
      <p>Tlf. +45 12 34 56 78</p>
      <p>CVR 123 456 78</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's pretty difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve, you may need to clarify this a little

Comment: consider creating a snippet with the relevant css too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like maybe you are looking for something like this when you have four blocks?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.region-footer {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  flex: 1;
}

.block-menu-block {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.block-block {
  min-width: 20%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.menu-name-menu-footer > .menu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-name-menu-footer > .menu > li {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 50%;
}



/* The following styles are just to help visualize what's going on */
.block,
a {
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
}

.menu-name-menu-footer > .menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-name-menu-footer > .menu > li:first-child {
  background: red;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.menu-name-menu-footer > .menu > li:last-child {
  background: green;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#block-block-2 {
  background: blue;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#block-block-1 {
  background: purple;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="region region-footer">
  <div id="block-menu-block-2" class="block block-menu-block">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="menu-block-wrapper menu-block-2 menu-name-menu-footer parent-mlid-0 menu-level-1">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="first expanded menu-mlid-734"><span class="nolink">Headline</span>
            <ul class="menu">
              <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-735"><a href="http://google.com">One page</a></li>
              <li class="last leaf menu-mlid-736"><a href="http://google.com">Another page</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="last expanded menu-mlid-785 social-menu-block"><span class="nolink">Social links</span>
            <ul class="menu">
              <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-784"><a href="http://facebook.com" class="social-facebook">Facebook</a></li>
              <li class="leaf menu-mlid-787"><a href="http://linkedin.com" class="social-linkedin">Linkedin</a></li>
              <li class="leaf menu-mlid-786"><a href="http://twitter.com" class="social-twitter">Twitter</a></li>
              <li class="last leaf menu-mlid-788"><a href="http://youtube.com" class="social-youtube">Youtube</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="block-block-2" class="block block-block">
    <h2>Some content</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, minim molestie argumentum est at, pri legere torquatos instructior ex. Vis id odio atomorum oporter.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="block-block-1" class="block block-block">
    <h2>Website info</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Address 9</p>
      <p>Zip city</p>
      <p>Tlf. +45 12 34 56 78</p>
      <p>CVR 123 456 78</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And something like this when you have five blocks...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.region-footer {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  flex: 1;
}

.block-menu-block {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.block-block {
  min-width: 20%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.menu-name-menu-footer > .menu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-name-menu-footer > .menu > li {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 50%;
}



/* The following styles are just to help visualize what's going on */
.block,
a {
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
}

.menu-name-menu-footer > .menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-name-menu-footer > .menu > li:first-child {
  background: red;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.menu-name-menu-footer > .menu > li:last-child {
  background: green;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#block-block-2 {
  background: blue;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#block-block-1 {
  background: purple;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#block-block-3 {
  background: orange;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="region region-footer">
  <div id="block-menu-block-2" class="block block-menu-block">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="menu-block-wrapper menu-block-2 menu-name-menu-footer parent-mlid-0 menu-level-1">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="first expanded menu-mlid-734"><span class="nolink">Headline</span>
            <ul class="menu">
              <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-735"><a href="http://google.com">One page</a></li>
              <li class="last leaf menu-mlid-736"><a href="http://google.com">Another page</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="last expanded menu-mlid-785 social-menu-block"><span class="nolink">Social links</span>
            <ul class="menu">
              <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-784"><a href="http://facebook.com" class="social-facebook">Facebook</a></li>
              <li class="leaf menu-mlid-787"><a href="http://linkedin.com" class="social-linkedin">Linkedin</a></li>
              <li class="leaf menu-mlid-786"><a href="http://twitter.com" class="social-twitter">Twitter</a></li>
              <li class="last leaf menu-mlid-788"><a href="http://youtube.com" class="social-youtube">Youtube</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="block-block-2" class="block block-block">
    <h2>Some content</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, minim molestie argumentum est at, pri legere torquatos instructior ex. Vis id odio atomorum oporter.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="block-block-1" class="block block-block">
    <h2>Website info</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Address 9</p>
      <p>Zip city</p>
      <p>Tlf. +45 12 34 56 78</p>
      <p>CVR 123 456 78</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="block-block-3" class="block block-block">
    <h2>5th Block</h2>
    <p>I'm the 5th block</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to set the width exactly with flexbox. Just make some initial width (for example if you have at most 5 blocks in footer, set the width to 20%).

Then, give each flex item `flex-grow:1`, this will ensure that the remaining space (for example if there are only four blocks) will be evenly distributed among all children.

```
.region-footer {
  display: flex;
}
.region-footer .block {
  min-width: 20%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

See the [Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more information.